# VBA. Create new workbooks using another workbook as a template and naming each new workbook from a list

Tags: vba

I have a workbook that I need to create 150 copies of.  I have the list of what I want to save each new workbook as in cells A1 to A150 in another workbook.

I've looked around but I can't find any code that does what I need.  If it makes it easier, I could put the list into the template workbook, but would need to delete that sheet from each new workbook before saving and closing it.

Comment: After watching [Excel VBA Introduction Part 5 - Selecting Cells (Range, Cells, Activecell, End, Offset)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c8reU-H1PKQ&t=3123s&index=5&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5), you should be able to write a macro that loops over `Range("A1:A150")`.  Next record a macro of you creating a workbook in the proper format.  If you get stuck comeback and post you code attempts.  Alternatively, try [Upwork](https://www.upwork.com/).

Comment: Are the 150 copies going to be identical?

Comment: Yes, the 150 will be identical at the point of saving them from the template as new files.  Then the team will work on the individual files and add different information to them manually.  this bit cannot be automated.  I just need 150 copies of the template with the new names from the list.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This code should help you:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsToCopy As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For a = 1 To LastRow
            Set wsToCopy = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TemplateSheet")
            Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
            wsNew.Name = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(a, 1).Value
            wsToCopy.Cells.Copy wsNew.Cells
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Explaining:
At a sheet named **"Sheet1"**, you need to have a list of the to-create sheets names, starting at the first row, always in the first column.

The macro will create a new sheet, rename-it and copy everything from the sheet **"TemplateSheet"**. And then, will pass to the next Sheet1's row.

So basically, just name your template sheet as "TemplateSheet" and add the 150 names at the first row of "Sheet1".

You can delete the template and the Sheet1 later.

Comment: The OP wants to create 150 Workbooks, not Worksheets.